# ant won't set sharing OWD on new objects?

Tags: sharing, ant, owd

I am using ant migration tool to deploy a new custom object to a target.  This object has external sharing OWD set to Private.  I've verified this in the object metadata.

```
<externalSharingModel>Private</externalSharingModel>
```

When I deploy, the object is created in the target but the external sharing is set to Public Read/Write instead of Private.

Why doesn't ant set the external sharing to Private?  My `package.xml` is ver 45 and I'm using the jar file from the v45 Spring 19 zip file.